# Sagemaker invoke endpoint returned value type?

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I have a classifier working with XGBoost in sagemaker, but despite the training set only having 1s and 0s in the first column (csv file, first column is assumed to be target in sagemaker xgboost), the algorithm returns a decimal.

First 3 records return 1.08, 0.34, and 0.91. I'd assume probabilities but 1.08? If these are rounded to 0 or 1 then they're all correct, but why is it returning non-class values?

Furthermore, the class only contains a predict method - is a predict probability method not possible without using your own model?

The code calling this is:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import boto3
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer
import sagemaker

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    numbers = request.args.get('numbers')

    #session
    boto_session = boto3.Session(profile_name="profilename",
                          region_name='regionname')

    #sagemaker session
    sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session(boto_session=boto_session)

    #endpoint
    predictor = sagemaker.predictor.RealTimePredictor(endpoint="modelname", 
        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
    predictor.content_type="text/csv"
    predictor.serializer=csv_serializer
    predictor.deserializer=None

    #result
    result=predictor.predict(numbers)
    result=result.decode("utf-8")
    return f'Output: {result}'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

The flask section works fine, I can retrieve predictions at 127.0.0.1:5000.

Sagemaker Version 1.3.0. Version 1.9.0 does not work - it requires fcntrl which is mac/linux only - see [this on their repo](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/311), apparently it's fixed on pypi but I've tried and the version doesn't change or fix the issue, so I'm stuck on 1.3.0 until they resolve it. Version 1.3.0 does not have a predict_proba method.

Comment: For binary classification (which it sounds like your case is), Sagemaker XGBoost's output is the probability. Check out this [notebook](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_applying_machine_learning/xgboost_customer_churn/xgboost_customer_churn.ipynb) on sagemaker predict example

Comment: Also a point to note is that, Sagemaker made an update with XGBoost. In case you are using an old container, use `predict_proba()` to get probabilities and in case of new update on Sagemaker `predict()` should be sufficient to return probability values. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @AjayBisht - Sagemaker 1.3.0, an old version, and it doesn't have a predict_proba method. How is the 1.08 response interpreted? That can't be a probability.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can add the code for predict and where you are calling predict?

Comment: @AjayBisht I've added the code in the original post, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Michael Brown, can you tell what objective function is used in the model? If you’re using  ‘binary:logistic’, the output should be probabilities within [0,1]. However, if you are using ‘binary:logitraw’, the output would be score before logistic transformation.